Dear Stack Exchange, please close this site
My reasoning is very simple. Purpose and working of the sites is that people votes for the best content.
Here people votes for their own political side. There is no way to assume a neutral or objective line, at least one extremist group will nitpick you. The foreseeable final position of the site is that it becomes a VLQ political newsletter of one of these extremist groups.
It just does not work. I would like to remember you to the, in theory, still working Interpersonal SE. As I can remember, that site has got a direction which even you could not openly accept any more. Very likely, case will be similar also on the politics SE.
Being a small site with a practically negligible external visitor count, even its media value is very minimal. But it is a very effective way to make so many enemies for you, as you only can.
You are medium-sized company in New York. It does not need a very deep knowledge of the USA inside politics, that likely no one would use the "redneck" word for you. But you could be still neutral, at least if neutrality would be possible with WW3 on the horizon and USA election in 2 months.
My opinion is that it is not possible. Thus, this site makes more harm.

If you want to get the attention of Stack Exchange itself, you would need to ask on Meta.SE. Nobody on Politics.SE has the power to unilaterally shut the site down, and nobody who does have that power is going to stumble across this question if it's on a site meta instead of the main one.


Here people votes for their own political side.

This is often true, at least on gray areas where a question or answer is not unambiguously good or bad (by the standards and customs of the site).
It is not always true.  A great many partisan posts get closed or deleted by people who have the same ideological bent as the poster.
For example, you felt you had to make this claim on another question.
Thing is, I mostly - personally - feel the same way as the OP myself (or rather the motives attributed for closure: aim to discredit motivated by dislike of the target).  However, it was just a very partisan question to be asking and this site's customs are, as much as possible, to avoid those types of questions.
No, we are not perfect at it.  There is a certain overall bias here.  But it is frequent that posters on Meta accuse the site's membership of leaning in the opposite direction of where it seems - to me - to be leaning.
You on the other hand seem to be thinking that if people disagree with your posts it automatically means a systemic bias.  That's certainly your prerogative but don't expect it to be very well received without some lot more solid arguments than you have been making.

I disagree that this site is that similar to Interpersonal SE.
Surely, one sees some unsourced answers here, but many Qs here have much more objective answers (backed by sources) than how do you approach your neighbor to stop feeding the bears.
BTW, this does come up once in a while here, see e.g. Is it hypocritical to force a subject as opinion-driven as "Politics" into a Stack Exchange format?

I think JoeW has right, it would be possible, except that not this happens. It could happen only if the majority of the voters would vote for some denomination-independent, science-like topic. But not that is the current practice of the site, and it is foreseeably not the practice - only very small part of the people would prefer a concept like "political science" before their own political views. That converts the site to a tribal arena battle. Obviously a "winner tribe" will soon emerge, and this "tribe" will be likely the same to whom also the SE company belongs, that is imho unavoidable.

Btw, Interpersonal SE had this process in some weeks after it was started. Then it became so crazy that not even the company wanted to openly accept them. The site still exists but they get a significantly decreased appearance in the "hot network questions" column, making their visitor count minuscule. A good politician never wants total victory. A good politician targets a more pleasant balance. That is what Interpersonal SE could not grab, and our current "winner tribe" can not grab here.

Note, the first revenge downs to my posts arrived just now. From an experienced SE troll: he seems knowing well that daily 2 downs are allowed per target per day. Probably he does not understand that he is actually giving me yet another reason to think that I am right with my this post.
